# Django __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Tags: python, html, django, web, passwords

Im trying to build a password reset system using the default django libraries. The problem is after trying to enter the site which is for changing it (PasswordChangeConfirm) this error trace appears.

```
Internal Server Error: /reset/confirm/MQ/atg5tq-aa6bcab1c34d1228cdd1970aaaa45252/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 284, in dispatch
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 308, in get_context_data
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 200, in get_context_data
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

my code:
views.py

```
class password_reset_view(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    form_class = CaptchaPasswordResetForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home:login')
```

urls.py

```
urls.py


from StartSite.views import password_reset_view
from StartSite.forms import NewPasswordResetForm
from StartSite.forms import CaptchaPasswordResetForm
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.urls.base import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from StartSite.views import PasswordResetView, password_reset_email_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('StartSite.urls')),

    path('reset_password/',
        password_reset_email_view.as_view(template_name="home/password_reset.html", form_class=NewPasswordResetForm),
        name="reset_password"),

    path('reset_password_sent/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="home/password_reset_sent.html"), 
        name="password_reset_done"),

    path('reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        password_reset_view.as_view(template_name="home/password_reset_form.html", form_class=CaptchaPasswordResetForm), 
        name="password_reset_confirm"),

    path('reset_password_complete/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="home/password_reset_done.html"), 
        name="password_reset_complete"),
]
```

forms.py

```
class CaptchaPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    new_password1 = forms.forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", 'type':'password'}))
    new_password2 = forms.forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", 'type':'password'}))
```

html

```
                  <form method="post" class="id_password_reset_form">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <p>Please enter your new password</p>
                      <h6 class="mb-0">New Password</h6>
                      <div class="pw_space2"></div>
                      {% render_field form.new_password1 class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="New Password" data-form-field="password"%}
                      <div class="pw_space"></div>
                      <h6 class="mb-0">Repeat New Password</h6>
                      <div class="pw_space2"></div>
                      {% render_field form.new_password2 class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Repeat New Password" data-form-field="password"%}
                      {{form.errors}}
                      <div class="pw_space2"></div>
                      <button style="background-color:#7231aa; border:#7231aa; color:white;" class="btn btn-secondary " type="submit">Change Password</button>
                      <a style="background-color:#7231aa; border:#7231aa; color:white;" class="btn btn-secondary " target="__blank" href="{% url 'home:profilesettings' %}">Cancel</a>
                </form>
```

Im using widget tweaks to render the form but I guess thats not the problem because for other things this works.

Answer (score 1):

Your `password_reset_view` inherits from [`PasswordResetConfirmView` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView), this view normally uses the form `SetPasswordForm` which takes the user as an argument (because it needs to set the users password), the problem is that your form `CaptchaPasswordResetForm` instead inherits from `PasswordResetForm` (incorrect) and hence you get an error. You should update your form class to inherit correctly:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import SetPasswordForm


class CaptchaPasswordResetForm(SetPasswordForm):
    ...
```

Comment: ok so this worked, but now I have another error:

https://hastebin.com/ijokirojuy.sql